# Button disabled although ICommand.CanExecute evaluates to true

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, commandbinding

I have two WPF projects, one is a .Net 4.7 dll and the other is a desktop app.

In my dll I have the classes `Viewport2D` and `ViewportCommands`

```
public static class ViewportCommands
{
    public static RoutedCommand ResetView { get; } = new RoutedCommand(nameof(ResetView), typeof(ViewportCommands));
    public static RoutedCommand ZoomFit { get; } = new RoutedCommand(nameof(ZoomFit), typeof(ViewportCommands));
}
```

My Viewport2D binds those commands in the ctor:

```
    public Viewport2D()
    {
        ...

        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.IncreaseZoom, ExecuteZoomIn, CanZoom));
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.DecreaseZoom, ExecuteZoomOut, CanZoom));
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ViewportCommands.ZoomFit, (o, e) => ZoomFit(), CanZoom));
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ViewportCommands.ResetView, (o, e) => Reset(), (o, e) => e.CanExecute = true));

        ...
    }
```

As you can see the `ResetView` command always evaluates to true. The `ZoomFit` command evaluates also to true in the most cases (and both functions are called, I checked that already).

In my WPF app I use this control:

```
  <controls1:Viewport2D x:Name="Zoombox" ...>
    <controls1:Viewport2D.InputBindings>
      <MouseBinding Gesture="{wpfUtils:MouseWheel Direction=Down}" Command="DecreaseZoom" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=Zoombox}" />
      <MouseBinding Gesture="{wpfUtils:MouseWheel Direction=Up}" Command="IncreaseZoom" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=Zoombox}" />
    </controls1:Viewport2D.InputBindings>
    ...
  </controls1:Viewport2D>

  ...

  <Button Content="100%" Width="70" Command="controls1:ViewportCommands.ResetView" />
  <Button Content="Zoom Fit" Width="70" Command="controls1:ViewportCommands.ZoomFit" />
```

The `IncreaseZoom` and `DecreaseZoom` are from the `NavigationCommands` class (part of .Net).

Both buttons from the snippet above are always disabled although they should be enabled. However zooming with both zoom commands works just fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you have any binding error in the output window of visual studio ?? because i found strange that you bind the Viewport2D=Gesture seems ok/// but the buttons on some static commands in ViewportCommands is not the same ???

Comment: try <Button Content="100%" Width="70" Command="{Bindig ElementName=Zoombox, Path =ResetView} "  />

Comment: The reference to the command is absolutely fine. I'm getting no errors or exception. How should `Command="{Bindig ElementName=Zoombox, Path =ResetView} " ` even work? ResetView is not a member of Viewport2D but of ViewportCommands.

Comment: wasn't sure...then change to something like Command="{Binding  controls1:ViewportCommands.ResetView" or move the binding code for these 2 commands in the window because it is in the Viewport2D actually

Comment: Neither of this is a problem. As I said, the methods, that are bound to those commands in Viewport2D get invoked. I already verified that. Command referencing like `Command="controls1:ViewportCommands.ResetView" ` is also valid. I use it everywhere in my code and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do a test 
if the binding is in a user control it does not work; if i change to MainWindow, it works...same xaml for both
----GOOD----

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ViewportCommands.ZoomFit, (o, e) => ZoomFit(), (o, e) => e.CanExecute = true));
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ViewportCommands.ResetView, (o, e) => Reset(), (o, e) => e.CanExecute = true));
    }


    public void ZoomFit()
    {

    }
    public void Reset()
    {

    }

}
 public static class ViewportCommands
    {
        public static RoutedCommand ResetView { get; } = new RoutedCommand(nameof(ResetView), typeof(ViewportCommands));
        public static RoutedCommand ZoomFit { get; } = new RoutedCommand(nameof(ZoomFit), typeof(ViewportCommands));
    }
```

----BAD----

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
        <Button Content="100%" Width="70" Command="local:ViewportCommands.ResetView" />
        <Button Content="Zoom Fit" Width="70" Command="local:ViewportCommands.ZoomFit" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>


public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ViewportCommands.ZoomFit, (o, e) => ZoomFit(), (o, e) => e.CanExecute = true));
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ViewportCommands.ResetView, (o, e) => Reset(), (o, e) => e.CanExecute = true));
        }


        public void ZoomFit()
        {

        }
        public void Reset()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Not the solution that I'd like to have but it works. Thanks